# How to Store and Retrieve a varbinary(max) Column in SQL Server

Tags: c#, arrays, sql-server, varbinarymax

I am developing an application in which I want to store the user's fingerprint into the database and then compare it with the one taken from the device.
I've been having certain issues while converting a `varbinary(max)` column back to a byte[]. I have tried to use the `GetSqlBinary` function but it gives me `indexoutofrangeException`.

I am using the code below for storing the template into the database but found that the value is the same for all users. (e.g. 0x000000)

```
public int insernewVoter(NSubject thumb) 
{
    connectionOpen();
    byteArray = thumb.GetTemplateBuffer().ToArray();
    int insert = 0;

    cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO VOTER (THUMB) VALUES(CONVERT(varbinary(max),'" + byteArray + "'))";
    int rowsupdated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (rowsupdated <= 0) {
        MessageBox.Show("Ho Gya");
    }
    else {
        MessageBox.Show("AP MAR KYN NAI JATA :D");
    }
    return 0;
    connectionClose();
}
```

Can anyone please show me how I can insert the byte[] into the varbinary(max) column and then retrieve it?

Comment: Yes it is but it inserting the same values for all users :?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should ALWAYS use parameters. Give this a shot:

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection("YOUR CONNECTION STRING ..."))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO VOTER (THUMB) VALUES(@THUMB)", conn)) {
    conn.Open();
    var param = new SqlParameter("@THUMB", SqlDbType.Binary) {
        // here goes your binary data (make sure it's correct)
        Value = thumb.GetTemplateBuffer().ToArray()
    };
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
    int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // do your other magic ...
}
```

**EDIT**

Since you've asked how to retrieve it, you can do something like (not sure of your exact requirements, but it should give you the idea):

```
private byte[] GetThumbData(int userId) {
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection("YOUR CONNECTION STRING ..."))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT THUMB FROM VOTER WHERE ID = @ID", conn)) {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", userId);
        return cmd.ExecuteScalar() as byte[];
    }
}
```

Comment: And how will I retrieve it after insertion?

Comment: Thank You so much you seriously solved my problem :) I was doing this fr round about 4 days and i thought that there is some kind of sdk issue

Answer (score 1):

if u have those finger prints in file format , thn u can use the following code , wch convert pdf into byte and byte again to pdf

```
  string filepath = Server.MapPath("~/pdf/" + file.FileName);
  byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
```

and pass this to Database field of varbinary 
now to retrive this content in to pdf u can use

```
 byte[] pdfcontent =  (byte[])DS.Tables[0].Rows[0]["PDFContent"];
```